# Logic phase shift detection

Tags: digital-logic

I have two logic signals that can be in two different configurations as shown in the image below.

[image: Two cases]

I would like to output a third signal that is HIGH for case A and LOW for case B. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Using what means (logic gates IC, mcu, fpga..)?

Comment: Preferably only logic gates IC.

Comment: My first thought was doing an XOR and checking which signal rose first, the XOR or the red one. This is more trouble than it's worth though, why not just do a state machine using a micro?

Comment: A feel a micro must be overkill for this. It should be possible with some logic gates, and possibly a flip-flop or two, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XOR both signals, the pulse train and the state one. Use this result as the clock for a positive edge trigger latch and the state signal as the value to latch. In state A the latch output is high and in state B the latch output is low.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Are you thinking that an XOR gate will produce no output if both of its inputs switch simultaneously?

Comment: I don't think it's terrible. In fact, I found it to work perfectly! I only needed to switch the two signals to the positive edge trigger latch: The state signal (red) should be the clock and the XOR output the latch. I'm guessing it was a mix-up by S3C. There is no issue with both blue and red switching simultaneously because the XOR output will always be low or high, for case A and B respectively, during a rising edge of the state signal. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The reason this is a dangerous answer is that it relies on precise relative timing of the two signals, and on the delay of the inverter. When both signals switch at the same time there is a very real risk of getting a glitch pulse from the XOR gate and violating the setup/hold time of the flip-flop. Be careful.

Comment: @JoeHass, Thanks for the warning. I suppose if one wants a solution that is as foolproof as possible, the reply by Dave Tweed is the way to go. But for my little application the gate and flip-flop solution is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

What you show is the input and output of a divide-by-two, the first one clocked by a rising edge, the second by a falling edge.

Apply your blue signal to divide-by two. For the first case, the output will either be the same as the red output, or the exact opposite. Feed the two trough an XOR, and you will get a steady output (neglecting some glitches due to delay differences!).

The same circuit with the second blue signal as input will produce a much more interesting output signal, which I leave for you to figure out. (I seem to have my teacher hat on.)

Answer (score 0):

You're basically saying that you want to know whether the edges on the red signal are nearer to the rising edges of the blue signal or to its falling edges.

This is not purely a logic problem — either combinatorial or sequential. In addition to some gates, you're going to need some analog hardware and a comparator of some sort to make the final decision.